# Wireless LAN not working on Toshiba Satellite L 510

Tags: wireless, networking

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 in my Toshiba Satellite L-510 laptop. Wireless LAN is not working.

I have a Realtek wireless network card installed. 
In **System Settings > Network** - it is showing "Unavailable". Kernel version is 3.2.0-73-generic.

```
sudo rfkill list all - command shows following result ....

1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
7: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`lsmod` command shows:

```
Module                  Size  Used by

nls_iso8859_1          12617  1 
nls_cp437              12751  1 
vfat                   17308  1 
fat                    55605  1 vfat
usb_storage            39646  1 
parport_pc             32114  0 
rfcomm                 38139  16 
ppdev                  12849  0 
bnep                   17830  2 
binfmt_misc            17292  1 
dm_crypt               22528  0 
joydev                 17393  0 
arc4                   12473  2 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     31823  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   174385  1 
snd_hda_intel          32719  3 
snd_hda_codec         109562  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
rtl8192se              94189  0 
snd_pcm                80916  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
rtlwifi                95855  1 rtl8192se
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25424  1 snd_seq_midi
mac80211              436493  2 rtl8192se,rtlwifi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51592  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
uvcvideo               67203  0 
videodev               86588  1 uvcvideo
snd_timer              28931  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
psmouse                97218  0 
serio_raw              13027  0 
btusb                  17948  2 
snd                    62250  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
bluetooth             158447  23 rfcomm,bnep,btusb
cfg80211              178877  2 rtlwifi,mac80211
soundcore              14635  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         14115  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
toshiba_bluetooth      12711  0 
toshiba_acpi           18158  0 
sparse_keymap          13658  1 toshiba_acpi
wmi                    18744  1 toshiba_acpi
mac_hid                13077  0 
lp                     17455  0 
parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
usbhid                 41937  0 
hid                    81731  1 usbhid
i915                  428458  4 
drm_kms_helper         45466  1 i915
drm                   197641  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
r8169                  56396  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13199  1 i915
video                  19115  1 i915
```

---

`rfkill unblock all` command did not solve the problem.

Any other suggestion? I should mention, I had purchased this laptop without OS and in dual boot partition I have Windows XP, where wireless is working.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your function keys, and on <kbd>F12</kbd> you should see a wireless tower icon.  Hold down the <kbd>FN</kbd> key in the lower left corner of the keyboard, and type the F12 key to turn on wireless.  The hardblock should be off, and you should see nearby access points,

---

I hope you are trying 12.04.5 at least, since earlier releases might not have had a working driver (not sure about the 8192, but the 8723 definitely had a problem, and both drivers were in the same source package.  Later releases like 12.10 fixed the issue, but that's out of support, so I'd suggest trying 14.04.

Comment: Function Keys in Ubuntu do not work for my Laptop; but this works in Windows.   Is it possible to enable wireless through command prompt terminal ?  If yes, kindly help .....

Comment: Did you own a similar model laptop. Can you authenticate this information from other sources?

Comment: I had a Toshiba satellite S855, no problems with any function keys, but the initial 12.04 release supported neither wireless nor ethernet.  Later releases fixed both problems.

Answer (score 0):

@ubfan1 was on the right track, but judging from your comment I suspect there may be another step you need to perform in order to enable your `fn` keys (and hence your wireless). You should edit one line in your `/etc/default/grub`, then reload grub and restart your computer. Here's how:

1. Backup your existing grub file, just in case:

`# cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.old`

2. Open grub file for editing:

`# gedit /etc/default/grub`

3. Look for a line that starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. Edit it so that it looks like this:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=Linux i915.i915_enable_rc6=1″`

This will light up a bunch of hotkeys and power management features.

4. Update grub and restart your computer:

`# update-grub && reboot`

5. If everything went well, you should be able to use your `fn` keyboard shortcuts. Otherwise you can restore your old grub file:

`# mv /etc/default/grub.old /etc/default/grub`

Source [here](https://blogs.harvard.edu/djcp/2011/11/kubuntu-11-10-on-the-acer-aspire-timelinex-4830tg-6450/).